# Safe time comparison in Moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

In current scenario it is safe to assume that all compared dates are of the same day, so only time is stored.

However, it is evident that there is non-zero probability of Y2K-like problem.

This piece of code may fail when being executed at 00:00 (roughly) if `momentTimeA` line is evaluated at 23:59:59.999 of one day and `momentTimeB` line is evaluated at 00:00:00.000 of another day:

```
// timeA is '06:00:00', momentTimeA is '2016-11-11T06:00:00.000';
const momentTimeA = moment(timeA, 'H:mm:ss');

// ...

// timeB is '03:00:00', momentTimeB is '2016-11-12T03:00:00.000';
const momentTimeB = moment(timeB, 'H:mm:ss');

// should be positive
momentTimeA.diff(momentTimeB);
```

Currently this code that does time comparisons runs synchronously, but it may become asynchronous later, this will considerably increase the risk.

How this problem should be addressed?

Comment: When you get a time of 0:00:00, try changing it to 0:00:01 (or whatever doesn't break it that's really close to 0:00:00, like 12:59:59), if the EXACT time isn't really necessary.

Comment: @Feathercrown I would prefer avoid this if possible, because time has to be quantized sometimes and some of comparisons are done against hardcoded '00:00' and '24:00', this will make the logic more complicated.

Comment: Well, hmm... I guess you could check if one is zero and just take the value of the other as the difference.

Comment: You can explicitly [set](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/) a given day (year, month, day) after you parse `time1` and `time2` so you will be sure that your moment objects point to same date. Anyway I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

Comment: @VincenzoC It looks like it should be done in the opposite way, because setting a date for existing moment object will ruin '24:00' special case. It is hard to believe that there's no builtin mechanism or a plugin for that.

Comment: @estus maybe you can add some details about how you want to manage `00:00` and `24:00`. Should `diff` between `00:00` and `24:00` give 0?

Comment: @VincenzoC Actually, diff should give 1 day (24:00 [is special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times) and it was quite useful in my case), unless 24-hour difference is overridden with `.date(...)`. But any way, 00:00 and 24:00, aren't applied simultaneously to the input.

Comment: No, the code you provided will not fail when executed at 00:00.  You are providing values for `time1` and `time2`, so the current time is not a consideration.  Only the values you gave as input matter.  Synchronous/Asynchronous is also irrelevant here, and so is Y2K.  Please edit your question to provide more details, and remove the irrelevant parts.  It's currently unclear what you are actually asking.

Comment: @MattJohnson Current date-time is a consideration. Because when only time is specified, Moment assigns current date to it automatically. And current date may differ within one function. The probability of is low but it exists and can be higher if async operations are performed, like DB queries. I hope I explained the problem clear enough.

Comment: Can't you just set both time with a same dummy date?

Comment: @BryanChen Currently I'm doing it like `momentTime = moment(time, 'H:mm:ss').year(...).month(...).date(...)` and I feel that it is a bit lame. I wonder if there are better ways to do that in Moment.

Comment: Now I see your edits, then yes - I understand that the current day is involved.  I'll answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are dealing with a time range that might cross over midnight, and you're not accounting for dates, then you will need to detect and adjust for this on your own.

```
// your inputs
var timeA = '06:00:00';
var timeB = '03:00:00';

// today's date as a string
var today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');

// both moments created using the same date
var momentTimeA = moment(today + ' ' + timeA, 'YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:ss');
var momentTimeB = moment(today + ' ' + timeB, 'YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:ss');

// check if midnight is crossed
if (momentTimeA.isAfter(momentTimeB)) {

    // move A back a day  (this is an assumption!)
    var yesterday = moment().subtract(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    momentTimeA = moment(yesterday + ' ' + timeA, 'YYYY-MM-DD H:mm:ss');
}

// now you can take the difference
var delta = momentTimeB.diff(momentTimeA);
```

Note you had A and B reversed in your original diff.  Assuming A comes first, use `B.diff(A)` to get a positive result.

Also, note that in the above code, it's important that you don't just subtract a day from the moment to adjust it, but that you re-create a new moment on yesterday at the given time.  This is because you are working in *local time*, which could possibly have a DST transition on one of the times provided.

Comment: Yes, a simple concatenation looks pretty good. Thanks for the notice on DST.